# How can I add an offset of 50px to this jquery animate function?

Tags: jquery

How can I add an offset of 50px from top to this function?

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add 50px like:-

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top + 50
}, 1000);
```